# How can I merge two nested dictionaries together?

Tags: python, dictionary, collections

I've got two nested dictionaries that have overlapping keys at the first level, but different keys at the second level. I want to merge them, so that the new dictionary has all of the keys.

```
A = {'id1': {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2 }, 'id2':{'key1': 3, 'key2': 4 }}
B = {'id1': {'key3': 5}, 'id2': {'key3': 6}}
```

The result should be

```
A_B = {'id1': {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 5}, 'id2':{'key1': 3, 'key2': 4, 'key3': 6}}
```

I know that I could do a `for` loop

```
for key in A:
    A[key].update(B[key])
```

But I would like to know if there is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could merge them in a dictionary comprehension:

```
A_B = {k: dict(A.get(k, {}), **B.get(k, {})) for k in A.viewkeys() | B.viewkeys()}
```

This uses the Python 2 [dictionary keys view object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects); in Python 3, use `dict.keys()` instead of `dict.viewkeys()`.

This'll merge *all* keys even if they are only present in one or the other of the dictionaries.

Demo with your input:

```
>>> A = {'id1': {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2 }, 'id2':{'key1': 3, 'key2': 4 }}
>>> B = {'id1': {'key3': 5}, 'id2': {'key3': 6}}
>>> {k: dict(A.get(k, {}), **B.get(k, {})) for k in A.viewkeys() | B.viewkeys()}
{'id2': {'key3': 6, 'key2': 4, 'key1': 3}, 'id1': {'key3': 5, 'key2': 2, 'key1': 1}}
```

or with input with more varied keys:

```
>>> C = {'foo': {'spam': 1, 'ham': 2}, 'bar': {'spam': 43, 'eggs': 81}}
>>> D = {'baz': {'vikings': 'singing'}, 'bar': {'monty': 'python'}}
>>> {k: dict(C.get(k, {}), **D.get(k, {})) for k in C.viewkeys() | D.viewkeys()}
{'bar': {'eggs': 81, 'monty': 'python', 'spam': 43}, 'foo': {'ham': 2, 'spam': 1}, 'baz': {'vikings': 'singing'}}
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the `**`. What does that do?

Comment: @2cents: it applies the keys of a dictionary as keyword arguments. See [What does \*\* (double star) and \* (star) do for Python parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36901). In this case it makes it trivial to merge two dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

1. Iterate dictionary `B`
2. Check if key from the `B` is present in the `A`- **Exception Handling**
3. If yes, then Update respective value of `A` by `B`.
4. If Not, then Add New Key with value in `A`

code:

```
>>> A = {'id1': {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2 }, 'id2':{'key1': 3, 'key2': 4 }}
>>> B = {'id1': {'key3': 5}, 'id2': {'key3': 6}}
>>> for i, j in B.items(): 
...      if i in A:
...          A[i].update(j)
...      else:
...          A[i] = j
... 
>>> A
{'id2': {'key3': 6, 'key2': 4, 'key1': 3}, 'id1': {'key3': 5, 'key2': 2, 'key1': 1}}
>>>
```

Comment: How is this better than the for loop I gave as an example?

Comment: @2cents: If `B` have key which is not present in the `A` then this will not come in output.

Comment: @2cents: You not handle exception when key is not present in the key in `A[key].update(B[key])` statement. This will raise `KeyError` exception.